# Laravel 5.5 conditional redirect on register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I want to redirect the uses when they register on different route depending on whether it has custom session or not
I managed to do that in the LoginController like so:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if (Session::has('userRequest')) {
            return route('request');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role->name == 'admin') {
            return route('admin-dashboard');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role->name == 'dealer') {
            return route('my-requests');
        }
    }
```

But when I try this in the RegisterController:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if (Session::has('userRequest')) {
            return route('request');
        }
    }
```

It throws `Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Redirector could not be converted to string` exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `redirectTo` must return a route/string. When the session does not have userRequest, the method returns null causing this error.

edit the method to be:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if (\Session::has('userRequest')) {
        return route('request');
    }
    return $this->redirectTo; // or any route you want.
}
```